# A Mystery in my Code

Tags: javascript, json, object, typo3

I have fixed the issue with ajax on typo3. Now comes another issue in hand. This time is related to returning the object found in the action to Javascript. So I tell you what I do exactly.

here is first my ajax call function:

```
function getContent(id)
      {
        console.log("Starting process ...");
          $.ajax({
                   async: 'true',
                   url: 'index.php',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: {
                       eID: "ajaxDispatcher",
                       request: {
                           pluginName:  'listapp',
                           controller:  'Pays',
                           action:      'getMyCompanys',
                           arguments: {
                               'id': id
                                      }
                               }
                   },
                   dataType: "json",

                   success: function(result) {
                      var data = JSON.parse(result)
                      console.log(data.nom);

                   },
                   error: function(error) {
                      console.log(error);
                   }
               });
      }
```

and here is the "getMyCompanys" action:

```
public function getMyCompanysAction()
    {

        $argument = $this->request->getArguments('id');
        $company  =  $this->entrepriseRepository->findBypays(2); // just to test with the id 2
        $result = (array) $company;
        return json_encode($result);
    }
```

Now on the console I get this Output:

```
{"\u0000*\u0000dataMapper":{},"\u0000*\u0000persistenceManager":{},"\u0000*\u0000query":{},"\u0000*\u0000queryResult":null}
```

So at the first glance , i thought the object was not passed to the javascript , but when I tried to add an attribute to the object $company ($company->att = 'val';)

I get this output :

```
{"\u0000*\u0000dataMapper":{},"\u0000*\u0000persistenceManager":{},"\u0000*\u0000query":{},"\u0000*\u0000queryResult":null**,"att":"val"}**
```

notice that the added attribute and its value get showed

so I now I'm convinced that there is something wrong with the object. I am also 100 % sure that the method findBypays(2); is working, I tried it in a listAction.

I don't really know what could be the problem :/

Just for your Information: this is part of an extension in typo3 that I developed myself using JBuilder

Comment: If you comment out `var data = JSON.parse(result)` does it work? You shouldn't need to parse data returned from a jQuery Ajax request.

Comment: I get the same output :  {"\u0000*\u0000dataMapper":{},"\u0000*\u0000persistenceManager":{},"\u0000*\u0000query":{},"\u0000*\u0000queryResult":null,"att":"val"}                           I think this has nothing to do with the JSON.parse otherwise the attribute (att = val ) won't be displayed ...

Comment: Please construct a minimal testcase that is entirely self-contained and demonstrates the problem. It's not clear here what output you expected instead.

Comment: @Andy: It doesn't work that way. If `result` were an object already, then `JSON.parse(result)` would simply fail ([with a syntax error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), since the string representation of an object — "[object Object]" etc — is not valid JSON), not result in an object with unexpected properties. Try `JSON.parse({})` in your console.

Comment: Fair enough. My point about not needing to parse the data still stands tho.

Comment: well I have 2 Models Country ( root model) and  Entreprise in my typo3 extension ... in the list View of the Model COuntry , I could list all countries and the Companies that belong to it ... on a change action on a country , I want to display only companies that belong to him (using ajax calls ) , the call is established and I what I'm expecting to get is just ( for now ) an object of Company

Comment: >>> JSON.parse({data})
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: I tried a trick : I added $company->nom as it's shown here : ` public function getMyCompanysAction()
  {
   $argument     = $this->request->getArguments('id');
   $company      =  $this->entrepriseRepository->findBypays(2);
   // just to test with the id 2
   $company->att = 'val';
   $company->nom = $company->nom;
   $result       = (array) $company;
   return json_encode($result);
  }` and the output is :   {"\u0000*\u0000dataMapper":{},"\u0000*\u0000persistenceManager":{},"\u0000*\u0000query":{},"\u0000*\u0000queryResult":null,"att":"val","nom":null}  . Somehow the object is null

Comment: but the function `$this->entrepriseRepository->findBypays(2);` works fine in another action in the same controller ... It's really weird ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after struggling for a long time , I tried a trick and it worked and it proved me that the json_encode does not return an object in typo3 eventhough I applied the :

```
$object->toArray() or (array) $object
```

to the object , so my solution was :

```
$companies = array();
foreach ($this->adresseRepository->findByland($id) as $company)
        {
            $companies[] = array(
                'uid'       => $company->getUid(),
                'firma'     => $company->getFirma(),
                'strasse'   => $company->getStrasse(),
                'plz'       => $company->getPlz(),
                'ort'       => $company->getOrt(),
                'land'      => $company->getLand(),
                'telefon'   => $company->getTelefon(),
                'email'     => $company->getEmail(),
                'webseite'  => $company->getWebseite()
            );
        }
return json_encode($companies);
```

and It Worked ;)